# Get time difference only from hours and minutes

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have two times one is `$InTime` : `12:55:10` and the other is `$OutTime` : `12:56:10`

So I think calculating the time difference should be:

```
$TotalTimeInOffice = $OutTime - $InTime
```

I want in hours so I think this should be the result `00:01`, but I am getting wrong result. With this calculation I am get `0` in the result, but why?

Here are some examples from database:

```
InTime is: 12:55:10
OutTime is: 12:56:09
Result Is: 0
InTime is: 12:24:45
OutTime is: 00:00:00
Result Is: -12
InTime is: 10:05:48
OutTime is: 10:06:11
Result Is: 0
```

and the PHP Code would be.

```
$timestart = $time_sheets->in_time;
$timestop = $time_sheets->out_time;
$time_diff = $timestop - $timestart ;
    echo "InTime is: $timestart <br />";
    echo "OutTime is: $timestop <br />";
    print_r('Result Is: '.$time_diff."<br />");
```

Comment: What exactly is `->in_time` and `->out_time`? String? Timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fails when midnight is involved e.g. `12:24:45 - 00:00:00` returns `-12:24:45`. You need to *correct* the times if they are located on either side of midnight:

```
function getDuration($timestart, $timestop) {
    $time1 = new DateTime("today " . $timestart);
    $time2 = new DateTime("today " . $timestop);
    if ($time2 < $time1) {
        $time2 = new DateTime("tomorrow " . $timestop);
    }
    $time_diff = $time1->diff($time2);
    echo " InTime is: $timestart\n";
    echo "OutTime is: $timestop\n";
    echo " Result is: " . $time_diff->format("%r%H:%I:%S") . "\n\n";
}
getDuration("12:55:10", "12:56:09");
getDuration("12:24:45", "00:00:00");
getDuration("10:05:48", "10:06:11");
getDuration("11:00:00", "01:00:00");
```

Output:

```
 InTime is: 12:55:10
OutTime is: 12:56:09
 Result is: 00:00:59

 InTime is: 12:24:45
OutTime is: 00:00:00
 Result is: 11:35:15

 InTime is: 10:05:48
OutTime is: 10:06:11
 Result is: 00:00:23

 InTime is: 11:00:00
OutTime is: 01:00:00
 Result is: 14:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should convert it to time() using strtotime();
then use $timeOutTime - $timeInTime;

```
   $timestart = $time_sheets->in_time;
    $timestop = $time_sheets->out_time;
    $timestart = strtotime($timestart);
    $timestop = strtotime($timestop);
    $time_diff = $timestop - $timestart ;
    echo data("h:i:s",$time_diff);
```

this should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Change It
$time1 = new DateTime($timestart);
$time2 = new DateTime($timestop);
// $time_diff = $timestop - $timestart ;
$time_diff = $time1->diff($time2);
echo "InTime is: $timestart <br />";
echo "OutTime is: $timestop <br />";
print_r('Result Is: ' . $time_diff->format('%H:%I:%s') . "<br />");
// End of Change
```

Problem Solved with DateTime function, but if there is any other good/better way then please post that answer too..

Comment: What if the in-time is `23:00:00` and out-time is `01:00:00`?

Comment: @SalmanA
So you gave me negative rep for this? :(, i asked the question remember.. i searched the internet alot and that solution seemed to give right answer for difference.
Thats why i said in the end if there is any other better solution please post that answer too.

Comment: Just add one day (but not 24 hours) to $time2 if $time2 is less than $time1 and it will produce the correct result (and I'll withdraw the downvote).